# Find a point on the horizontal axis by a robot where the axis stretches from -infinity to +infinity

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, brute-force

If I have a point x on the horizontal axis where the axis stretches from -infinty to +infinity and I have a robot who has to find the position of the point x on those axis.

How can the robot find the position of the point provided it can be given only three commands-

1. To move on the right
2. To move on the left
3. To ask check whether x is positioned at the given point or not.

I thought about the answer and I could think of this solution-
If the robot starts from position 0 in the axis and then moves to the left by 1 unit(i.e. at coordinate -1),then again it can be be given to check whether x is present on -1 or not.If its not present then move to the right by 2 units(i.e. at coordinate +1) and again check the same  by 3rd command.If it still couldn't find the point x ,then again move 3 units to the left(i.e. at coordinate -2).If x is still no present then again move to the right by 4 units(i.e. at coordinate +2).It keeps on doing this until it find the point x at a specific location on the axis.

What is the right way to solve this problem in an efficient manner?

Comment: Arithmetic operations are not in the list of allowed commands.

Comment: @n.m. yes ,no arithmetic operations is allowed.The robot can just move to the right or left by some units or can check whether x is present at a certain position or not

Comment: Since the robot doesn't get any feedback (i.e. if it has come closer to x) there is no more efficient algorithm than brute force, as long as x is uniformly distributed (meaning the chance that x=n is equal for any n). your method is one way of brute forcing(probably the easiest).

Comment: So how do you move N steps to the right and then N+1 steps to the left?

Comment: @n.m. that is upon me,when I want the robot to stop(means if I have to move n steps to the right or n+1 steps to left)

Comment: why you are able to as if `x = n` but your aren't able to ask if `x > n` ?

Comment: just a thought: if it takes extra time to turn the robot, i.e. move to a different direction than before, you might move in bigger blocks. For example walk 1000 steps to the left, 2000 to the right, 3000 to the left etc.

Comment: @WiiMaxx because that would be a simple binary search :P

Comment: Let me try again. How do you cause the robot to move N steps if it has no understanding of numbers?

Comment: @sotix: there's no such thing as an uniformly distributed unbounded integer.

Comment: @sotix i thought his robot is maybe only able to handle max 3 commands

Comment: @n.m. Sorry, I don't see any mention of integers. There's just an axis with an infinite amount of points where x could be hidden. And regarding the arithmetics: I understood OP as "I can send one of those three commands to a robot and I am trying to find x with the robot. So I might send a series of commands like this: 1,3,2,2,3,1,1,1,3, ...". It's a quite strange problem of course.

Comment: @sotix ah i didn't think about it in this way and the robot can't say he his n < x because it's just a bool-sensor  so i would suggest moving more than 1 step in on direction would be faster in the RL because the way he moves would be shorter

Comment: There is a misunderstanding here. A robot is a programmable device. You don't send commands to it as it goes, you program it beforehand and release it, and then it works autonomously. If you remotely control it, it's not a robot, it's a remotely controlled device which has nothing to do with programming and so is off topic here.

Comment: @sotix If it took bigger steps like 1000 steps in one go then what if my robot was very near to the starting point(like at coordinate -3).How would I check it on that position then?

Comment: @n.m. The question doesn't lays emphasize on the fact whether the robot is a programmable device or its a remotely controlled device.The main motive of the question is to solve it in an algorithmic way!

Comment: @user2718073 you don't take bigger steps, you just keep walking in the same direction for a longer time. but this has no effect on the efficiency on the algorithm, it only does if (and only if) turning your robot around takes somehow extra time

Comment: There's nothing to solve in an algorithmic way here. You have a countable set of points. Order it in some way, go. Problem solved. That's what you have done. There's no algorithm to speak of, just different orderings of the countable set. You cannot compare their efficiency until you define a distribution of your input data, so it doesn't matter which one you choose.

Comment: @sotix oh yeah.sorry I got confused.But still I am 1000 steps to the left then moving 2000 steps to the right .And later on I find out that x was on +3.Then in that case,moving 1000 steps to the left would be a waste of time.Don't you think so? That was the reason why I chose 1 step at a time.